# Index and match between cells that has lines breaks

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

Cell A2 is the data given which has different lines breaks. I separated the data before and after "-" as shown in B2 & C3. Then I sorted the data of C2 from lowest to largest in D2. The desire result is cell E2. I would like to have a user define function to get index B2 by matching D2 from C2. Please note A2 has four values in 4 lines breaks in one cell not in every cell there is a value, please find attached.

Comment: If you sorted in C2 then why is 65 first and 43 second? This is not clear - please improve.

Comment: So you want the data in A2 to be sorted by the "after -" value and then to cut the "after -" value out of the original data?

Comment: Variatus has solved it in the first answer function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UDF below will do what you want. Call it from the worksheet like `=InexMatch(A2)`. Make sure that the cell you place it in has its `WrapText` property set to True.

```
Function InexMatch(Cell As Range) As String
    ' 003

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim Tmp As String
    Dim Done As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    Arr = Split(Cell.Value, Chr(10))
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        Sp = Split(Arr(i), "-")
        Arr(i) = Sp(1) & "-" & Sp(0)
    Next i

    Do
        Done = True
        For i = 0 To UBound(Arr) - 1
            If Val(Arr(i + 1)) < Val(Arr(i)) Then
                Tmp = Arr(i)
                Arr(i) = Arr(i + 1)
                Arr(i + 1) = Tmp
                Done = False
            End If
        Next i
    Loop While Not Done

    On Error Resume Next
    ReDim Sp(UBound(Arr))
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        Sp(i) = Split(Arr(i), "-")(1)
    Next i
    InexMatch = Join(Sp, Chr(10))
End Function
```

The function will return a null string if the referenced cell is blank. It can deal with cells that have fewer than 4 lines. It will fail if the CR isn't ANSII Chr(10) or the dash isn't a ANSII Chr(45) - a minus sign. It has no provision for incomplete lines within cells, meaning lines which don't have characters on both sides of a dash.

In order to restore the original format in the sorted string please delete all the lines below the end of the Do Loop in the code above, starting with `On Error Resume Next`, and replace them with the following.

```
For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
    Sp = Split(Arr(i), "-")
    Arr(i) = Sp(1) & "-" & Sp(0)
Next i
InexMatchV2 = Join(Arr, Chr(10))
```

Comment: This works perfectly, can you edit it to return 
B1-43
D4-51
A-65
C-230
Appreciate your support! really helpful!

Comment: I have appended modification instructions to my above post. Have a good day!

Comment: I have modified the code to suits a different format as well, I have 3 dashes in each line break and it works 
`Arr(i) = Sp(0) & "-" & Sp(1) & "-" & Sp(2) & "-" & Sp(3)`
Thank you very much!!